# Embedded collection of Forms: The embedded form field won't render

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I am new to this topic and am trying to embedd a collection of Tag forms inside the Task Form. I am trying to duplicate the simple example given on the page http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/form/form_collections.html . Even when I copy the given code, It just display the Task form's description field and not the Tag form's name field. I tried some things but haven't been able to figure it out.
This is how the rendered page looks:
[image: Here is the screenshot of the browser output page]

Below is the twig file:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

    <h3>Embedded Collection of Forms!</h3>

    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form.description) }}
    {{ form_row(form.tags) }}
    <h3>Tags</h3>
    <ul class="tags">
        {% for tag in form.tags %}
             {# {{ form_widget(tag) }} #}
            <li>{{ form_row(tag.name) }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
    </ul>  
    {{ form_end(form) }}

{% endblock %}
```

Below is the controller code:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use AppBundle\Entity\Task;
use AppBundle\Entity\Tag;
use AppBundle\Form\TaskType;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $task = new Task();

        // dummy code - this is here just so that the Task has some tags
        // otherwise, this isn't an interesting example
        $tag1 = new Tag();
        $tag1->name = 'tag1';
        $task->getTags()->add($tag1);
        $tag2 = new Tag();
        $tag2->name = 'tag2';
        $task->getTags()->add($tag2);
        // end dummy code

        $form = $this->createForm(new TaskType($task));

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array(
                    'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

Below is the TaskType.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;

class TaskType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('description');

        $builder->add('tags', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => TagType::class
        ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Task',
        ));
    }
}
```

Below is the TagType.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class TagType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Tag',
        ));
    }
}
```

Below is the Task Class

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class Task
{
    protected $description;

    protected $tags;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->tags = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTags()
    {
        return $this->tags;
    }
}
```

Below is the Tag Class

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

class Tag
{
    public $name;
}
```

Comment: inside your controller you have `$form = $this->createForm(new TaskType($task));` change that to either  `$form = $this->createForm(new TaskType(), $task);` or  `$form = $this->createForm(TaskType::class, $task);`  i will take a closer look later

Comment: Thank you Dheeraj. This did fix the problem. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't render a form row twice.
Remove this line in your twig template: `{{ form_row(form.tags) }}`

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

    <h3>Embedded Collection of Forms!</h3>

    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form.description) }}
    <h3>Tags</h3>
    <ul class="tags">
        {% for tag in form.tags %}
             {# {{ form_widget(tag) }} #}
            <li>{{ form_row(tag.name) }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
    </ul>  
    {{ form_end(form) }}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info jahller

Comment: Hi @utkarsh2k2 if this has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Hey @Jahller, The info you provided was correct, however it did not solve the issue I was facing. As it turns out than Dheeraj's solution mentioned in the above comment did. But I did give your solution a +1. Thanks again :)